# Unable to open STS IDE

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

Not sure what has happened with my system now, once I have reboot my windows laptop then after I am unable to open STS than.

It is showing error -

[image]

above log has following contain :

> > !SESSION 2017-05-14 21:00:11.181 ----------------------------------------------- eclipse.buildId=3.8.1.201607290850-RELEASE-e46 java.version=1.8.0_131
> >     java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32,
> >     ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
> >     org.springsource.sts.ide Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32
> >     -arch x86_64 -product org.springsource.sts.ide
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-05-14 21:00:14.019 !MESSAGE
>   Application error !STACK 1 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)    at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.lambda$7(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:380)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createUniqueWorkspaceNameMap(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createRecentWorkspacesComposite(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:325)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.createDialogArea(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:176)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.TitleAreaDialog.createContents(TitleAreaDialog.java:158)
>     at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.create(Window.java:426)  at
>   org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.create(Dialog.java:1095)     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:783)     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.ChooseWorkspaceDialog.prompt(ChooseWorkspaceDialog.java:114)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.promptForWorkspace(IDEApplication.java:342)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.checkInstanceLocation(IDEApplication.java:261)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:128)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)  at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)

Not sure now from where that ArrayIndecOutoFBound Exception is coming, I have googled the same but nothing solved out my problem.

Comment: Have you checked the error log? What's it showing?

Comment: Thanks @DarrenForsythe I come to know my problem's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find below file in your STS install configuration directory and delete it -

```
/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs Blockquote
```

beware now you guys would not get previous workspace suggestions like before as we have just deleted the one of the setting file from STS. 
Hope this will help.